# Mongoengine 0.8.0 breaks my custom setter property in models

Tags: python, mongoengine

in Mongoengine 0.7.10, I can still do things like:

```
class User(db.Document):
    email = db.EmailField(unique=True, required=True)
    _password = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)

    @property
    def password(self):
        return self._password

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self._password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
user = User(email='1@1.com', password='12345')
```

However, the above code breaks in 0.8.0:
`ValidationError: ValidationError (User:None) (_password.Field is required: ['User'])`

It seems that MongoEngine doesn't recognised my custom password setter during initiation. I have to manually write these to fix it:

```
user = User(email='1@1.com')
user.password='12345'
```

This is probably due to the below changes(from [Mongonengine 0.8 upgrading notes](http://docs.mongoengine.org/en/latest/upgrade.html#document-definition)):

`Previously, if you had data the database that wasn’t defined in the Document definition, it would set it as an attribute on the document. This is no longer the case and the data is set only in the document._data dictionary:`

I would like to know if this is intended or is it a bug in MongoEngine? What is the best practice to write the custom property setter in my model?

Comment: Did you try extending `__init__`?

Comment: @ThomasOrozco Do you mean extending like this? `def __init__(self, email, password):`  Mongoengine will pass `_password` into `User.init()` method, when mongoengine loads the documents from database. This would crash the app because `__init__` method does not accept `_password`.

Comment: You should reuse the signature of the method that already exists, potentially extending with `*args` and `**kwargs`.

Comment: for additional info, checkout this thread: https://github.com/MongoEngine/mongoengine/issues/366

Answer (score 5):

Try this code:

```
class User(db.Document):
    email = db.EmailField(unique=True, required=True)
    _password = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True, db_field='password')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            db.Document.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

            if 'password' in kwargs:
                self.password = kwargs['password']

    @property
    def password(self):
        return self._password

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self._password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
user = User(email='1@1.com', password='12345')
```

It works for me.

Comment: Also if you want to save it as `password` not as `_password` in db, then do this `_password = StringField(max_length=255, required=True, db_field='password')`

Comment: `FieldDoesNotExist: The fields "{'password'}" do not exist on the document "User"` with mongoengine==0.15.0

Answer (score 2):

You should use the Document `clean` function, [described in the mongoengine documentation](http://docs.mongoengine.org/guide/document-instances.html).

```
class User(db.Document):
    email = db.EmailField(unique=True, required=True)
    password = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)

    def clean(self):
        if not hashed(self.password):
            self.password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(self.password)

    def hashed(self, password):
        return  # boolean check of whether the password is already hashed

user = User(email='1@1.com', password='12345')
user.save()
```

Every time you call `user.save()`, it will now check if your password resembles a hashed value, and if not, hash it before updating the database.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a bug - it cleans up some other bugs and was the intended action as mentioned in the upgrade documents.  However, thats no good for this situation!

I think a custom method for creating the password hash would be better eg: set_password check_password etc...

There have been PasswordField implementations in the past and that is something I will add to extras-mongoengine.

Comment: Hi Ross, I have seen your update regarding PasswordField here https://github.com/MongoEngine/extras-mongoengine/issues/8 but still can't figure out how to use this patch, I am using mongoengine 0.8.7 and also try to reinstall as per instruction given here https://github.com/noQ/mongoengine BUT When i try to use PasswordField it show undefined error. Also checked in mongoengine.fields but there is no PasswordField. Can you please help me out. :)

Answer (score 1):

In more recent versions of MongoEngine, you will get a

```
FieldDoesNotExist: The fields "{'password'}" do not exist on the document "User"
```

When you try to use an `@property` like some of the above answers.

To avoid this, use a `'strict':False` in your meta dict.

I wish readers to know I invested considerable time to bring you this information, that is all.

Answer (score 0):

This is no elegant solution, but I really like to push my form directly into the model with secure password hashing on the model level and not within one or many views. Simply rename `password` to `_password`, run the mongoengine document validation and set `self._password`:

```
class User(db.Document):
    """User model."""

    username = db.StringField(max_length=50, required=True, unique=True)
    _password = db.StringField(max_length=255, required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['_password'] = kwargs.pop('password')
        db.Document.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.password = kwargs['_password']

    @property
    def password(self):
        return self._password

    @password.setter
    def password(self, password):
        self._password = bcrypt.generate_password_hash(password)
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example, I overwrite the password with hashed value and store it as BinaryField.

```py
class Users(Document):
    name = db.StringField(required=True)
    password = db.BinaryField(required=True)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'password' in kwargs:
            password = kwargs['password']
            if not isinstance(password, bytes): # if it creates from user input, not from DB's load
                kwargs['password'] = bcrypt.hashpw(password.encode('utf-8'), bcrypt.gensalt())
        Document.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
```